# Best way to hash passwords in PHP?

Tags: php, hashing, passwords

I've switched to PHP 7.0 very recently and I was wondering that if password_hash was better than making your own salt and using the crypt function. I have three examples of code and I don't know which make the passwords the most secure.

Example #1 (BCRYPT):

```
$options = [

    'cost' => 12,

];

$hashed_password = password_hash("foo", PASSWORD_BCRYPT, $options);
```

Example #2 (PASSWORD_DEFAULT):

```
$options = [

    'cost' => 12,

];

$hashed_password = password_hash("foo", PASSWORD_DEFAULT, $options);
```

Example #3 (CRYPT FUNCTION):

```
$Blowfish_Pre = '$2y$05$';
$Blowfish_End = '$';

$Allowed_Chars = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789./';

$Chars_Len = 63;

$Salt_Length = 21;

for( $i = 0; $i < $Salt_Length; $i++ )
{
$salt .= $Allowed_Chars[mt_rand(0,$Chars_Len)];
}

$bcrypt_salt = $Blowfish_Pre.$salt.$Blowfish_End;

$hashed_password = crypt($password, $bcrypt_salt);
```

Comment: Please, for the love of all that is holy, do *not* encrypt passwords! Ever! Passwords should *never* be stored (for authentication purposes)! Not even encrypted! You should *only* store a (possibly peppered) salted cryptographic hash of the password. [Note: the obvious exception here is when you are writing a password safe like OSX's Keychain or KeePassX or something like that. In that case, you obviously *do* need to store the password, and of course you should do that encrypted. But for authentication purposes the statement holds: *never* store them. Ever.]

Comment: In PHP the prefered way now is to just use the `password_hash` without providing alhorithm specification or salt yourself (the method generates the salt for you). It is also recommended to alter the number of iterations so your hash function takes a reasonable time on your CPU to prevent brute force, among other things.

Comment: @WateR make sure to use password_verify() and not == to compare hashes since password_verify() it is implemented to resist timing-attacks.This is a MUST. using password_needs_rehash() is recommend.

Answer (score 1):

In your `crypt` alternative, you construct the salt using [`mt_rand`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mt-rand.php).  This is not recommended, because the cryptographic quality (i;e. it is not random enough) is not sufficient. This is explicitly documented:

> **CAUTION:**  This function does not generate cryptographically secure
>   values, and should not be used for cryptographic purposes. If you need
>   a cryptographically secure value, consider using random_int(),
>   random_bytes(), or openssl_random_pseudo_bytes() instead.

---

The second alternative seems the most promising.  The implementation will take care of the **secure** salting, as underlined in the manual:

> **Warning:**  The salt option has been deprecated as of PHP 7.0.0. It is now preferred to simply use the salt that is generated by default.

and:

> **Caution**: It is strongly recommended that you do not generate your own salt for this function. It will create a secure salt automatically
>   for you if you do not specify one.

This means also that if soem weakness is identified in this function, you'll get an improved one, whereas for your custom crypt call, you'd maybe never find out if there would be a flaw.

---

The first alternative is nice for compatibility.  But compared to the second one, it truncates user password at 72 chars.  Ok:  I admit not to use such a long password, but in some environments, users are instructed to use long passphrases.  the default parameter doesn't have this constraint and is hence stronger.

Note also that the length of the hash is 60 bytes in this situation.  The default algorithm doesn't specify the exact length but can be longer and may in the long run use stronger longer hashes.

Comment: I want to store the salts in the database so I don't have the decrypt the passwords every time someone logs in. Also i'm confused that the second one would be stronger because I've read online that Bcrypt one of the strongest and still hasn't been broken til this day.

Comment: `password_hash()` uses the [modular crypt format](https://pythonhosted.org/passlib/modular_crypt_format.html) and automatically stores the salt as part of the hashed password. You always have to hash the incoming password during login, so saving the salt yourself won't save you any processing time. Currently `password_hash()` uses bcrypt as the default algorithm, but if a stronger algorithm is added the default algorithm will automatically change while if you specify bcrypt explicitly you won't ever get the stronger algorithm.

Comment: @WateR 1) "I want to (..) don't have to decrypt (...)": sounds that you're somehow weakening the security: be careful; what simplifies your work will also simplify the hacking.   2)  the question is about evolution of your software: you can't assume that crypt with [Schneier's](https://www.schneier.com/academic/) blowfish will remain the safest forever.  So `password_hash` let's you not to loose focus and will evolve to safer/faster algorithms when the current ones could get outdated.

Answer (score 0):

The first example is fine. It's only downside is that you won't be able to profit automatically from stronger default algorithm. If you maintain your code, that shouldn't be a big deal.

The second example has the problem that the interpretation of the `cost` parameter has been specified for the bcrypt parameter. Its successors might interpret it differently or not at all. If you use `PASSWORD_DEFAULT` I'd avoid specifying algorithm specific options and just use the defaults.

The third example is problematic because it uses a non-cryptographic RNG do generate the salt. While salts don't need to be secret, this will result in common collisions due to the crappy RNG seeding. If you need to support older versions of PHP, use [ircmaxell/password_compat](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat)
 which uses `crypt` under the hood, but has been carefully written by an expert.